# How do I remove alpha channel from old BPG files to be viewed by new libbpg?

Tags: pictures, bpg

I have a couple of old BPG-encoded pictures. As PNG was used as input format, they got an (empty) alpha channel, so can't be decoded by newer libbpg:

> version 0.9.4:
>
> - Modified alpha plane encoding to allow progressive display and
>     streaming encoding. This change is incompatible, so images
>     containing alpha from the previous versions of the format cannot be
>     decoded.

I don't need this alpha channel. How do I losslessly convert them to new BPG format?

Answer (score 0):

Use my tool to remove alpha channel from them: https://gist.github.com/vi/9297cd5bf80f0b34e8a2

It removes alpha channel from old BPG files, making them decodable by newer BPG decoders.

```
$ bpgdec -i test.bpg
size=1606x1263 color_space=YCbCr alpha=1 premul=0 format=4:2:0 limited_range=0 bit_depth=8 animation=0
$ bpgdec test.bpg
Could not decode image

$ bpg93_remove_alpha.pl < test.bpg > test.noa.bpg
magic: 425047FB
PixelFormat: 1  alpha: 1  bitdepth: 8
ColorSpace: 0  ExtPresent: 0  Alpha2: 0 LimitedRange: 0 ReservedZero: 0
Width: 1606  Height: 1263
Picture data length: 81969
Alpha data length: 239

$ bpgdec -i test.noa.bpg 
size=1606x1263 color_space=YCbCr format=4:2:0 limited_range=0 bit_depth=8 animation=0
$ bpgdec test.noa.bpg
$
```